# How to disable expression engine URL

Tags: php, url, seo

want to disable the SEO URL structure of Expression engine, i don't understand how to do that

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

I presume what you're looking for is a way to break the strict template_group/template structure that EE adheres to by default. If so then the easiest way would be to use [Freebie](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie) (free addon).

Freebie will allow you to define URL segments which EE will ignore completely so you can build up your own custom URL structure, integrate with Structure or anything else you need to achieve.